# how to save value in rxjs before map

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

i have an odata result that looks like this

[image]

i want to pickup "value" from here and before that i want to save the @odata.count in localStorage or may be just log it.

```
  getAllBankAccounts(url: string): Observable<BankAccount[]> {
return this.http.get(url).pipe(map((res) => res['value']));
}
```

how can i return observale array that is in "value" property but store '@odata.count' before that. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [tap](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap) to tap into the value of an observable.

```
getAllBankAccounts(url: string): Observable<BankAccount[]> {
  return this.http.get(url).pipe(tap(res=>console.log(res['@odata.count'])),map((res) => res['value']));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to save @odata.count into local storage try this new version for the last answer

```
getAllBankAccounts(url: string): Observable<BankAccount[]> {
  return this.http.get(url).pipe(tap(res=>localStorage.setItem('odata',res['@odata.count'])),map((res) =>{ 
//here do anything 
res['value']}));
}
```